# How to collapse an array of key filtered objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Let's assume I'm obtaining an array of objects from a Node Repository, for example:

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "SNKEP1",
    ep: 1,
    season: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "SNKEP2",
    ep: 2,
    season: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "SNKEP3",
    ep: 3,
    season: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "SNKEP1",
    ep: 1,
    season: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "SNKEP2",
    ep: 2,
    season: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "SNKEP3",
    ep: 3,
    season: 2
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "SNKEP1",
    ep: 1,
    season: 3
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "SNKEP2",
    ep: 2,
    season: 3
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "SNKEP3",
    ep: 3,
    season: 3
  }
];
```

And I want to have this result:

```
const filteredEps = [
  {
    season: 1,
    ep: [{/* filtered eps */}]
  },
  {
    season: 2,
    ep: [{/* filtered eps */}]
  },
  {
    season: 3,
    ep: [{/* filtered eps */}]
  },
];
```

How do I get this result?

Comment: please make an attempt yourself before asking

Comment: Please try something first (use `.filter`, or `.map`, or a `for` loop for instance) then we can help you if you're stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
let filteredEps = [];
for (const value of array) {
    let [eps] = filteredEps.filter((_eps) => _eps.season === value.season);
    if (eps) {
        eps.ep.push(value.ep);
    } else {
        filteredEps.push({season: value.season, ep: [value.ep]});
    }
}
```